# Issue with In-App Purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm testing my in-app purchase in sandbox mode but I dun understand why the in-app purchase alert box keeps popping up even though i've clicked Buy...

On the second time it pops up after i clicked 'Buy', i clicked 'Cancel' and there was an error:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code1, address=0x6000008)
```

My .m:

> -(void)updateCredit{
>       //Adding to plist
>       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
>   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
>       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
>       NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray *currPlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
>
> NSString *lastEx = [currPlist objectAtIndex:0];
> int lastScore = [[currPlist objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
> int numberOfTries = [[currPlist objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
> int totalScore = [[currPlist objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
> int avg = [[currPlist objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
> int credit = [[currPlist objectAtIndex:5] intValue];
>
> credit += 10;
>
> NSMutableArray *updatePlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
> [updatePlist addObject:lastEx];
> [updatePlist addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:lastScore]];
> [updatePlist addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfTries]];
> [updatePlist addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:totalScore]];
> [updatePlist addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:avg]];
> [updatePlist addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:credit]];
> [updatePlist writeToFile: path atomically:YES]; 
>  }
> ```

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            [self updateCredit];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error updating credit" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert2 show];
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect your problem is in one of your `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol methods. The code above looks fine for the purposes, but it does reference other code you haven't posted.

Comment: Updated the code but the alert view is by itself and only present if it fails. The problem arise on successful purchase. There hasn't been any unsuccessful attempt hence the invalidity of the alert view being the cause.

Comment: Yes, it is something to do with the AlertView. I suspected its due to the position of the cancel button conflicting with the "Cancel" and "buy" button array in memory? So i'm still figuring out how to overcome that...